# Why UART voltage level on ATMEGA64A-AU are different?

Tags: avr, uart

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321100/why-i-cant-put-command-in-atmega64a-au-serial) I tried to measure voltage on RX1 and TX1 on [ATMEGA64A-AU](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8160-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega64A-summary.pdf) (the second USART) the RX1 voltage is about 3 volt and TX1 is 5 volt(straight out of the chip) which I've provided for the chip and the module rx/tx voltage level is 5 volt. the USART0 both RX and RX voltage is 5 volt.

As of previous question, the problem is I can't send command to GSM module, I got confused the RX voltage which has a different voltage than the module shouldn't be working but it is vise versa.

Why this happens? Why USART1 has different voltages on this chip?

Comment: What is your AVR supply voltage? What GSM module you use and what is the IO voltage for it? Provide datasheet link for GSM module.

Comment: did you connect the ground of both modules together...?

Comment: @vicatcu I did connected the ground together, if I don't the receive wouldn't worked either .

Answer (score 1):

Given that the receive pin is driven by something else, the voltage would be whatever the driving circuit drives it to. GSM modules usually run at 3v3 (actually they often run lower) so there is no reason for one to drive to 5 volts.

The ATmega's transmit pin, on the other hand, would drive to its supply voltage (except to the degree to which it droops under load).  Apparently that supply is 5 volts, which means you'll almost certainly need some sort of level translation to safely feed the GSM module.

Given that you provide no information about your setup, not much can be said beyond that.

Comment: The GSM module has a jumper to select voltage level for RX/TX pin, which I've select it to be 5V because I measured USART0 voltage level and they were 5V and The measurement I did was when I disconnected rx/tx pin off the MCU to module so I was wounder why same USART pin have a different voltage level out of the MCU!

Comment: Again, because is comes from a different source.  There is no reason at all to expect the two signals to have the same voltage when they have entirely different origins.  If you want any more useful response, **you must provide actual engineering documentation of your setup** including *internal schematics* of the GSM module.